# C preprocessor #error in header file included in multiple source files

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I have two source files, main.c and datamgr.c - and two header files, config.h and datamgr.h
The testing system we're using expects these files, and only these files.

main.c:

```
#include "datamgr.h"
#include "config.h"

int main() {
    custom_type a = 1;

    a = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

datamgr.c:

```
#include "datamgr.h"
#include "config.h"

custom_type foo() {
    custom_type a = 1;
    return a;
}
```

datamgr.h:

```
#ifndef DATAMGR_H
#define DATAMGR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

custom_type foo();

#endif
```

config.h:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#ifndef SET_MAX_TEMP
#error "Max temperature not set."
#endif

#ifndef SET_MIN_TEMP
#error "Max temperature not set."
#endif

typedef custom_type uint16_t

#endif
```

Now, the problem is that I can only define `SET_MAX_TEMP` and `SET_MIN_TEM`P in main.c, but both main.c and datamgr.c need both the header files. So if I leave them undefined in datamgr.c I get a compiler error. However, if I do define them in datamgr.c and later overwrite them in main.c, I get a different compiler error.

Please, any assistance as to how to get this horrible setup to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can they only be defined in main.c? You should be able to define them in the header file (only) and it'll work in all files.

Comment: Because main.c is the file that our testing system uses to implement the test scenario. So if they're left undefined in main.c -> error. The datamgr.c and both header files are left untouched by the testing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass these `define`s directly while compiling:

```
gcc -DSET_MAX_TEMP -DSET_MIN_TEMP <your files>
```

Answer (score 0):

In datamgr.c do:

```
#define SET_MAX_TEMP
#define SET_MIN_TEMP

#include "datamgr.h"
#include "config.h"

#undef SET_MAX_TEMP
#undef SET_MIN_TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said:

> Because main.c is the file that our testing system uses to implement the test scenarios.

In that case, make sure that the testing system defines those macros in the command line of the compiler for every file being compiled.

Comment: I should've been more clear, the testing system is for our university to test our code's functionality. It can't be altered.

Comment: @fakeskuH Sounds like you need to talk to a teacher's assistant, and ask how you're supposed to do it. The sensible solution would be to `#define` the MAX and MIN in either config.h or datamgr.h. If they want you to do something different, then they need to tell you what that is.